# Derivative of function with Fourier transform

Tags: integration, derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I want to calculate below derivative with Fourier transport:
$\partial_{x}p(x,t)= \partial_{x} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(k,t) e^{-ikx} dk$$ = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p(k,t)  i k e^{-ikx} dk$
in my case, p(k,t) is a $ e^{-|k|^{\alpha}t} $. So, above integral is zero! But in the case of $\alpha=2$, $p(x,t)$ is a guasian distribution which its derivative is not zero!! Could anyone underestand what is the problem in this case?

Comment: When you write $p(k,t)$ is $e^{|k|^{\alpha}}$, do you mean $p(k,t)$ is $e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}$?

Comment: Yes, it was a writing mistake. Thank you. @OlivierOloa

Comment: Why do you say the integral is $0$?

Comment: Do you mean $\partial_x P(x,t)$ where $P(\cdot,t)$ is the Fourier transform of $p(\cdot,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\alpha>1$. One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  i k e^{-ikx} dk&=\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  i k e^{-ikx} dk+\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  i k e^{-ikx} dk
\\\\&=-\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  i k e^{+ikx} dk+\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  i k e^{-ikx} dk
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}  k\: \frac{e^{+ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i} dk
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-|k|^{\alpha}}   k \sin(kx) dk
\\\\&\neq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could your last integration be solved analytically?

Comment: Do You mean it has a close form?

Answer (score 1):

Why would the integral always be zero? Note that $p(k, t)ik$ is an odd function in $k$, but $e^{-ikx} = \cos(kx) - i\sin(kx)$ is neither even nor odd.

Comment: You are right! I didn't notice it. But for optional $\alpha$, could this integral be solved? @dominik

Comment: @saranj I don't think there is any simple representation, see http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~goran/research-reports/psrr18-2009.pdf